# Create an incoming call screen on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-phone-call

I'm looking for a way to show the default "incoming call screen" to the user.

The user should be able to interact it (i.e. answer/deny) and my application should receive this chosen action.

Although I can design my own "incoming call screen" for sure (kind of faking the default one), but is there any way to ask Android (on a physical device) to display the default screen (I would populate the phone number / name to display).

I don't want to create this screen from scratch, as it won't be exact with the system default, and it would take quite some time for me.

(Motivation: I'm customizing an Android phone, it will show an incoming call screen when the call is actually coming into my other phone - two phones will negotiate the notification/actions via some common interface like Bluetooth or Wifi).

ps: rooting is available, so I have literally no limitation.